# Objective c- get sub json string in json array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I have a JSON of the format like this

```
"MaintanenceHeaders":[{}],
"MaintanenceRules":[{ }],
"FaultRules":[{}]
```

How can I get json string MaintenanceHeaders without parsing the string?
Like:
"MaintanenceHeaders":[{}]

Comment: how can get string without parsing? can you elaborate your question please?

Comment: I get json string after post call. It has 6 object in it. I want to get one object as a string. Like I'm get an object after post call

Comment: Sefa, as a beginner try to implement from your self from Google. By the way you are getting data in form of dictionary so try to get value by KEY 'MaintanenceHeaders'  . Follow few link for parsing e.g. http://roadfiresoftware.com/2016/12/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-3/   http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/   . Moreover '[' represents ARRAY while '{' represents dictionary

Comment: Convert it to a dictionary. Afterwards, convert the `MaintanenceHeaders":[{}]` to JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"MaintanenceHeaders":@[@{@"M1":@"V1", @"M1":@"V2"}, @{@"M2":@"V1", @"M2":@"V2"}],
                           @"MaintanenceRules":@[@{@"M3":@"V1", @"M3":@"V2"}],
                           @"FaultRules":@[@{@"F1":@"V1", @"F1":@"V2"}]};

    for (NSString *key in dict) {
        id object = dict[key];
        NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\":%@", key, [self jsonStringFromObject:object]];
        NSLog(@"Output: %@", output);
    }
}

- (NSString *)jsonStringFromObject:(id)object {
    NSError * err;
    NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:&err];
    NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return jsonString;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Output: "MaintanenceHeaders":[{"M1":"V1"},{"M2":"V1"}]
Output: "MaintanenceRules":[{"M3":"V1"}]
Output: "FaultRules":[{"F1":"V1"}]
```